# ActionController::UnknownFormat for json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Im using this code in my controller to give json response

```
respond_to do |format|
        msg = { :status => "ok", :message => "Success!" }
        format.json  { render :json => msg }
end
```

is giving me an error -> `ActionController::UnknownFormat on the "respond_to do |format|" line.`

In my routes.rb,
 Im using this

```
 get '/xyz' => 'xyzs#abc'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to do it like:

```
    msg = { :status => "ok", :message => "Success!" }
    render :json => msg
```

Comment: Forgot to mention .. I was using a rails-api project ..and your answer worked for me ... thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Please check whether JSON Mimetype is added to your **config/initializers/mime_types.rb**

```
Mime::Type.register "application/json", :json
```

Comment: the line wasnt added .. tried adding it but it made no difference

Comment: Have you restarted the server and checked?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a class level `respond_with` call in your controller or in `ApplicationController`. If there is one, check if `:json` is passed as one of its params.

Comment: Hi, I am very new to rails .. can you please explain a little more ?

Comment: About 4 question like this with many answers on stackoverflow but only this answer help in my case.